# Using protractor to click menu and submenus

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I am very new to protractor and unable to write code to select the menu and submenus and click it which is present inside div id="navbar" .. Someone help me..
I have some problems posting the html code so i have sent this link.

[click to see the html codes](http://1strackcourier.com/protractor.txt)

i need something like this or something else

```
var temp = element(by.attribute('[href="#/admin/teachingModules"]'));<br/>
        temp.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of leads :

- take a look at [the Protractor doc](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions)
- your menu might have a transition/animation. If that's the case, you'll need to wait a little before actually trying to click on it